# Configuring UnetStack in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, unetstack

I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDEA for my UnetStack Project.

I'm following this blog

https://blog.unetstack.net/using-idea-with-unetstack

I get this error when done following this:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

Comment: Do you have Groovy installed?

Comment: Hi! I’m the author of that article. Could you tell me how you added the Unetstack libraries to IntelliJ? If possible, do try the same on Ubuntu and let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: @Kootli yes I have Groovy installed

Comment: @shortstheory I'm trying the same on Ubuntu. I used Unet Simulator 1.4 and added the libraries

Comment: @Aradhana18 I also had the same issue. I'll answer it hope it solves your problem

Comment: @Aradhana18 also note that you do not need to have groovy installed as the Unet libraries contain the necessary groovy libs to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This happened to you because you ran your simulation as a groovy script and not as the configured application. Run it as application and groovyStarter will not even be used.

Comment: Could you tell me how you configured it as a groovy script? I will update that blog post to make it clearer that it should be configured as an application if you can tell me how you initially conifgured it.

Comment: you can't run it as a groovy script because unetstack itself has groovy libraries which have to be linked.